# Divergence Operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

How do you simplify such operators:
$$(\vec{a}\cdot\nabla)\vec{b}$$

I would appreciate any reference/name regarding this so I can try to understand this.

Comment: What do you mean by ``simplify''?

Comment: I mean how do I apply such operators? What are such operators called?

Comment: they're called directional derivatives (of $b$ in the direction of $a$), or yet better, the (standard) connection, when it's denoted $\nabla_a b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about specific name for it other than advection operator as mentioned in Fluid Dynamics regarding [Navier-Stokes equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#Convective_acceleration). You can apply it directly through definitions of each operator consisting your complex operator. For example, if it acts on a scalar field $b$
$$
(\vec a \cdot \nabla)b = a_ib_{,i} = a_1\frac {\partial b}{\partial x_1} + a_2\frac {\partial b}{\partial x_2} + a_3\frac {\partial b}{\partial x_3}
$$
If it acts on a vector field $\vec b$, then you just apply it for each component, so
$$
\left [ (\vec a \cdot \nabla)\vec b \right ]_j = a_i b_{j,i} = a_1\frac {\partial b_j}{\partial x_1} + a_2\frac {\partial b_j}{\partial x_2} + a_3\frac {\partial b_j}{\partial x_3}
$$

### Notes

\begin{align}
a_ib_i &= a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3\ \text{(Einstein summation rule)} \\
\vec a \cdot \nabla &= a_i \nabla_i = a_i \partial_i \\
\partial_i b &= b_{,i}
\end{align}

Comment: That is clear enough. Thanks.